# Permutations Function Issue

Tags: python, function

I've been struggling with defining a function that returns the permutations of a given array.
I have written the code below:

```
def gPermutations(array):
    result = []
    idx = 0
    for element in array:
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if i != idx:
                z = array[:array.index(element)]
                z.append(array[i])
                s = z[:] + array[array.index(element)+1:]
                s[i] = element
                result.append(s)
                idx += 1
    return result
```

This code seems to work by returning some of the permutations of an array, but doesn't return all of them, and sometimes duplicates a certain permutation.  May someone please explain what is the issue with my code? Thanks!

Comment: can you add an example with output. Your code is very hard to understand

Comment: Do you want an explanation for why _this_ code is wrong, or do you just want replacement code that works correctly?

Comment: An explanation of the code's. issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `permutations` method from `itertools`

```py
In [1]: from itertools import permutations                                                                                                                 

In [2]: arr = [1,2,3,4]                                                                                                                                    

In [3]: for perm in permutations(arr, len(arr)): 
   ...:     print(perm) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                    
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 3)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 4, 3)
(2, 3, 1, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 1)
(2, 4, 1, 3)
(2, 4, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2)
(3, 2, 1, 4)
(3, 2, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 2, 1)
(4, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 1, 3, 2)
(4, 2, 1, 3)
(4, 2, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 1, 2)
(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want all the permutations (re-orderings?) of your list, I'd use the `itertools` package:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> array = [1, 2, 3] 
>>> print(list(permutations(array)))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```